# Error while opening Rstudio throught Terminal

Tags: unix, server, rstudio, conda

I am working with Unix and from now on I need to use the University server to run some packages in R.

1.I assessed the server by ssh 
2.I downloaded miniconda 
3.source ~/.bashrc
4.Downloaded Rstudio 
5. conda install -c r rstudio

And when I am trying to open Rstudio I am receiving the following error

'QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display'

Any help will be super useful.

Comment: @pu239ppy  based on the link you send me yesterday I have to get X11 forwarding working over ssh . First step is make sure /etc/ssh/sshd_config contains:
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10                                                                                                     SO  file seems to be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending you your platform and your university's security policy this may or may not work
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely

In short you need to explicitly enable X11 forwarding (though I was under the impression that it is on by default).  Also you need to run an X11 server, there are a few on windows and MacOS.  If the above does not help, it is most likely due to a security policy and you may want to speak to your university's SysAdmin

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info